# Cannot load JDBC driver on JBoss Fuse

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse, jboss-esb, jboss-developer-studio

guys! I have a project in Jboss Developer Studio. If  I run project on Local Camel Context - it works. If I run project in Jboss Runtime Server 6.3, I see this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not found by xml-to-database [297]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1853)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:958)
at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.utils.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:47)
at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.utils.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:69)
... 35 more
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from bundle 297 (xml-to-database)
at org.apache.camel.core.osgi.utils.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:78)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1422)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1373)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1046)
at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.processingSqlBySettingAutoCommit(JdbcProducer.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.component.jdbc.JdbcProducer.process(JdbcProducer.java:67)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:681)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:609)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:238)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:108)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

But I installed this bundles in Fuse:

```
wrap:mvn:com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.2.1.jre8
wrap:https://maven.lib.umd.edu/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
```

And create maven build with external archive sqljdbc4-4.0 on Jboss Developer Studio

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project is not able to find the "SQLServerDriver" file.
 could you pls download the jar file and add in your project lib folder and deploye again and try ..

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqljdbc420jar.htm

Comment: ,How to do it? I run the server and add project through Jboss Developer Studio